# How to calculate the number of days between dates using Pascal?

Tags: datetime, pascal, freepascal

I keep the date in the format DateTime.
Which algorithm for calculating the number of days?

Comment: Could you not just subtract one from the other (assuming the Time part was zeroed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [DaysBetween](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/dateutils/daysbetween.html)